# Question was downvoted and put on hold. I don't follow

Tags: discussion

I went through great length researching this topic because it's been a rather pain in my rear, and I reference what I consider an appropriate amount of detail, and describe the symptom, and lo and behold, I'm greated with downvotes and eventually the question is put on hold.

[Windows updates and driver search consume massive amounts of RAM. Seriously? [on hold]](https://superuser.com/questions/942924/windows-updates-and-driver-search-consume-massive-amounts-of-ram-seriously)

I'm not following what's going on here.  And neither was another user who also noticed that I got downvoted.  It was my understanding that downvotes are for bad questions, not questions that you may or may not like.  Isn't that the case here on Superuser?

Getting back to the topic, some people are replying to the actual topic of the question, and we might even have an answer.  In most of my searches I found the same and similar problems, but no solutions, hence coming to the Stack Exchange ecosystem.

Comment: I can see 2 possible reasons for closure: the three questions and problems of this nature can often have many possible causes.  I streamlined the three questions into the key one, and magicandre1981's answer sheds light on the issue.  See if that gets the question reopened.